# how can i match two strings even if they are 1 character different?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database of sentences, and a problem where sentences like "i'm good" do not match to "im good" and vise versa or "is that mine?" not matching with "is that mine" and vise versa when i would want them to be detected as a match.

I had made complicated and messy functions trying to do this with wildcards and researching but its just a big mess. and im sure there must be a way to search with this 1 character lee way. If i can i would like to control which characters get this lee way, like in my examples the main problem causers are the question mark and the half quote. (? ').

im currently using a plane select query with php and mysql to do the matching queries.

i would love some help to figure this out so i can clean up the big mess of code that is currently doing the job inconsistently.

in case anyone wants to see the code query checking for matches is like this:

```
$checkqwry = "select * from `eng-jap` where (eng = '$eng' or english = '$oldeng' or english = '$oldeng2') and (jap = '$jap' or japanese = '$oldjap' or japanese = '$oldjap2');";
```

the purpose of the query is to just check if there is already a translation with the $eng and $jap already in the DB.  the reason you see $oldeng $oldeng2 and $oldeng3 and so on is like i said, my messy foolish attempts to match even if there is or is not a question mark and so on. where some of the $oldeng variables have questions marks or halfquotes and so on and the others dont. there is more code above appending and remove question marks and stuff. yes its a big mess.

Comment: you want to look for some sort of [String Metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) algorithm that will tell you how far "apart" two strings are, and adjust for your level of tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a String Metric algorithm as mentioned above, PHP has this function built in http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php as well as http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php.

MySQL doesn't implement this (specific algorithm) natively but some people have went ahead and wrote stored procedures to accomplish the same: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

In my opinion using a String Metric that can handle arbitrary changes is better then stripping out punctuation, and can also catch omissions, transpositions, etc...

Comment: i just made a function to match where similar text returns higher than 91% out of the results that the full index compare gives. a small problem with that is that with a small sentence, like 1 word. even one character difference will return only like 85%, so i need to have flow accounting for the length of the sentence. but i can put it all in one comparing function so in the end i will still have cleaned up the mess i made earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to simply strip non-alphanumeric characters out before comparing the strings.

Comment: yes that would work with the one way compare, but not with the vise versa. what about the sentences already in the DB that have ? or ' and someone searches for it without that. then it will not match still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function in sql to replace "'" with "" and "?" with "".

Comment: thats what im currently doing, and like i said, its a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [natural language full text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) in MySQL.  Add a FULLTEXT index to the eng column.

```
 ALTER TABLE `eng-jap` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `full` (`eng`) ;
```

Then, use match function:

```
 select * from `eng-jap` where match(eng)  against ('Im happy');
```

This will return both *I'm happy* and *Im happy*

If you select the relevance score like:

```
  select id, match(eng)  against ('Im happy') from `eng-jap` where match(eng)  against ('Im happy');
```

you can use it  to further process the matches in PHP and filter.

[EDIT]: Just verified that the relevance score for *yesterday* and *yesterday?* are the same too:

```
 select *, match(eng)  against ('yesterday') as mc from `eng-jap`
```

Result is:

```
  6, yesterday?, 0.9058732390403748
  7, yesterday, 0.9058732390403748
```

Note: For Fulltext index to be applied, your mysql engine has to be MyISAM. Also, the sentence has to contain more than 3 characters. The index doesn't seem to match a word like 'yes'.

Comment: I think Aea's answer also looks like it would solve this for me, but since you included the steps in more detail i gave you the check mark. I havn't tried it yet but Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: actually this is matching all kinds of stuff that i dont want it too. is there a way to adjust the tolerance?